# Use gensim phraser on pandas column using apply method

Tags: python, pandas, gensim, n-gram, phrase

I am trying to use gensim phraser on a column in a df. The sample df is given below

```
col1   col2
1      "this is test1 and is used for test1"
2      "this is content of row which is second row"
3      "this is the third row"
```

I have wrote a method for bigrams

```
def bigrams(text):
    bigram = Phrases(text, min_count=1)
    bigram_mod = Phraser(bigram)
    return [bigram_mod[doc] for doc in text]
```

And I tried

```
df['col2'].apply(bigrams)
df['col2'].apply(lambda x: bigrams([x])) - so that the text is enclosed in list
```

but I get the characters as output and not the bigrams. What am I missing here.

Answer (score 2):

`Phrases` expects a corpus that's already been tokenized.

Your question doesn't currently show what value of `text` you're supplying to your `bigrams()` function, but it can't be those row values as plain strings: you'll have to break them into your desired words, somehow, first.

Separately: don't expect any meaningful results from a tiny toy-sized example, as `Phrases` requires lots of data for its statistics-based word-pairing to be useful. And note that even when useful, the pairings often won't match human-level ideas about what the meaningful groupings/entities would be – both missing pairings we'd like, and making pairings we wouldn't, and even careful parameter tuning leaves such 'unnatural' choices. But, such `Phrases`-processed text is still often useful for back-end classification/info-retrieval purposes.

Comment: I have tried to use apply on a column that has token in a list. In that case, each word is split into characters in the output. The text is put in the question is sample text. I cannot put the actual text here.

Answer (score 0):

So gensim phraser expects a list of list of tokens
So my solution that worked is 
Convert text to tokens
convert tokens into list of list

```
df['tokens']=df['text'].apply(tokenization_function)
df['tokens']=df['tokens'].apply(lambda x:[x])
df['bigrams']=df['tokens'].apply(bigrams)
```